# Inserting words between strings

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP form that involves a multiselect checkbox. I want to load the options that were selected by the user into a string and echo it. I want to separate the options with commas and the word "and".

For example:
If a user selects just Option 1, I want to echo "opt1".
If a user selects Option 1 and Option 2, I want to echo "opt1 and opt2"
If a user selects Option 1, Option 2, and Option 3, I want to echo "opt1, opt2, and opt3".

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<p><b>Product:</b><br>
<INPUT NAME="product[]" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="opt1">
  Option 1<BR>
<INPUT NAME="product[]" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="opt2">
  Option 2<BR>
<INPUT NAME="product[]" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="opt3">
  Option 3<BR>
<INPUT NAME="product[]" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="opt4">
  Option 4<BR></p>
```

Thanks for helping a PHP noob!

Comment: I have tried using the checkboxes as separate items. (By that I mean that each "NAME=" was different for each checkbox. I'm pretty sure that won't work though because I won't be able to use a count for the number of options selected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want these `opt` values to dynamically load during run-time, you will need to use Javascript. PHP loads on the server-side when the page is initially loaded so when a user checks a box, PHP cannot do anything by itself to `echo` values to the screen again.

Comment: I'm actually looking to echo the values after the user presses a submit button, so unless I am mistaken, I think I can use PHP. Right?

Comment: After they press the submit button, if the form it is linked to goes to another page, you may do it (if the echo values exist on another page). Otherwise, you must use javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to do three cases; one if there is only one selection, one for two selections, and one for more-than-2 selections.

This (untested) solution should get you in the right direction:

```
<?php

$products = (isset($_POST['product']) && is_array($_POST['product'])) ? $_POST['product'] : array();
$count = count($products);

$options = '';
if ($count == 1) {
    $options = $products[0];
} else if ($count == 2) {
    $options = $products[0] . ' and ' . $products[1];
} else if ($count > 0) {
    // remove (and store) the last product selected
    $last = array_pop($products);
    // join all remaining products by comma-separation, then add the last product
    // to the end with an "and"
    $options = implode(', ', $products) . ' and ' . $last;
}
echo $options;
?>
```

Please note, the above solution also assumes you're receiving the user-selection via a POST array.

Comment: The seems to be what I'm looking for. Thank you very much. When I test it though, I get this: 0) { $last = array_pop($products); $options = implode(', ', $products) . ' and ' . $last; } echo $options; ?>

Comment: I copy/pasted the code and ran it and didn't receive any errors. Also, I tested it by placing this above everything: `code`$_POST['product'] = array('opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4');`code` and it worked fine; Can you post a use-case how you're testing it?

Comment: I think I was testing wrong. I was opening the local HTML file in a browser and trying to execute the PHP. That probably explains why it was not working. I am installing XAMPP now.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, correct grammar states that you don't put a comma before the final `and`.

So, what you really need to do is separate the last two words with `and`, and the others with `,`.

Well, assuming you have your words in an array already, all you have to do is `array_pop` the last element off the end. Then `join` the remaining elements with `,`, and put it together with the last one with `and` in between. If there is only one word, just return it.

We're not here to write code for you, but this shoud help you along.

Comment: "In many languages the serial comma is not the norm and may even go against punctuation rules." - In fact it seems like only the US find it normal to add that piece of punctuation.